# Finding social network of a friend

Tags: c++, algorithm, edit-distance

Following is the code which finds the social network of a friend (i.e. friends of friends and so on). Friends definition is, ff W1 is friend of W2, then there should be Levenshtein distance equal to 1. It is working fine with a smaller dictionary, but is taking a lot of time with a bigger dictionary.

Need some code review and advice.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <queue>
#include <fstream>  
#include <iostream>  
#include <sstream>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
#include <set>

class BkTree {
    public:
        BkTree();
        ~BkTree();
        void insert(std::string m_item);
        void get_friends(std::string center, std::deque<std::string>& friends);
    private:
        size_t EditDistance( const std::string &s, const std::string &t );
        struct Node {
            std::string m_item;
            size_t m_distToParent;
            Node *m_firstChild;
            Node *m_nextSibling;
            Node(std::string x, size_t dist);        
            bool visited;
            ~Node();
        };
        Node *m_root;
        int   m_size;
    protected:
};

BkTree::BkTree() {
    m_root = NULL; 
    m_size = 0;
}

BkTree::~BkTree() { 
    if( m_root ) 
        delete m_root; 
}

BkTree::Node::Node(std::string x, size_t dist) {
    m_item         = x;
    m_distToParent = dist;
    m_firstChild   = m_nextSibling = NULL;
    visited        = false;
}

BkTree::Node::~Node() {
    if( m_firstChild ) 
        delete m_firstChild;
    if( m_nextSibling ) 
        delete m_nextSibling;
}

void BkTree::insert(std::string m_item) {
    if( !m_root ){
        m_size = 1;
        m_root = new Node(m_item, -1);
        return;
    }
    Node *t = m_root;
    while( true ) {
        size_t d = EditDistance( t->m_item, m_item );
        if( !d ) 
            return;
        Node *ch = t->m_firstChild;
        while( ch ) {
            if( ch->m_distToParent == d ) { 
                t = ch; 
                break; 
            }
            ch = ch->m_nextSibling;
        }
        if( !ch ) {
            Node *newChild = new Node(m_item, d);
            newChild->m_nextSibling = t->m_firstChild;
            t->m_firstChild = newChild;
            m_size++;
            break;
        }
    }
}

size_t BkTree::EditDistance( const std::string &left, const std::string &right ) {
    size_t asize = left.size();
    size_t bsize = right.size();
    std::vector<size_t> prevrow(bsize+1);
    std::vector<size_t> thisrow(bsize+1);

    for(size_t i = 0; i <= bsize; i++)
        prevrow[i] = i;

    for(size_t i = 1; i <= asize; i ++) {
        thisrow[0] = i;
        for(size_t j = 1; j <= bsize; j++) {
            thisrow[j] = std::min(prevrow[j-1] + size_t(left[i-1] != right[j-1]), 
                    1 + std::min(prevrow[j],thisrow[j-1]) );
        }
        std::swap(thisrow,prevrow);
    }
    return prevrow[bsize];
}

void BkTree::get_friends(std::string center, std::deque<std::string>& flv) {
    if( !m_root ) return ;
    std::queue< Node* > q;
    q.push( m_root );

    while( !q.empty() ) {
        Node *t = q.front(); 
        q.pop();
        if ( !t ) continue;
        size_t d = EditDistance( t->m_item, center );
        if( d == 1 ) { 
            if ( t->visited == false ) {
                flv.push_back(t->m_item);
                t->visited = true;
            }
        }
        Node *ch = t->m_firstChild;
        q.push(ch);
        while( ch ) {
            if( ch->m_distToParent >=  1 )
                q.push(ch);
            ch = ch->m_nextSibling;
        }
    }
    return;
}

int main( int argc, char **argv ) {
    BkTree *pDictionary = new BkTree();

    std::ifstream dictFile("word.list");
    std::string line; 
    if (dictFile.is_open()) {
        while (! dictFile.eof() ) {               
            std::getline (dictFile,line);
            if ( line.size()) {
                pDictionary->insert(line);
            }
        }
        dictFile.close();
    }
    std::deque<std::string>  flq;
    pDictionary->get_friends("aa", flq);
    int counter = 0;
    while ( !flq.empty()) {
        counter++;
        std::string nf = flq.front();
        flq.pop_front();
        pDictionary->get_friends(nf, flq);
    } 
    std::cout << counter << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

My first thought is that you may want to profile the code and see where most of the time is being spent.

My second thought comes from examining the code.  You are doing a lot of `xxx[i]` or similar inside loops where `i` is simply being incremented.  To me, that suggests using an iterator (`std::vector<size_t>::iterator`).  `xxx[i]` often can result in more calculations than the simple incrementing of an iterator.

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few tips:

The loop to read from the file is better written as:

```
{
  std::ifstream dictFile("word.list");
  std::string line; 
  while (std::getline (dictFile,line)) 
  {               
    if (line.size())
      pDictionary->insert(line);
  }
}
```

Next, most of your methods take `std::string` by value - which could be expensive depending on your compiler - you may be better off passing a const reference instead (you seem to mix and match).

Next, in your `Node` constructor, consider using a member intialization list to set the members rather than in the body of the constructor. Why is this relevant, in your approach, the member is constructed and then later assigned to.

The above may make a difference, now that that's done, profile like @jwernerny says, and it may reveal where your true hot spots are. For a profiler, if this is windows and visual studio, consider the intel profiler (I guess this is homework, so you can probably use the evaluation version) - it's pretty good at highlighting hotspots.

Answer (score 0):

It might be because you are using a queue to store your Nodes in q in get_friends. You are doing a breadth-first search, meaning a lot of insertions and removals. Note that for breadth-first you can also use a last-in-first-out queue, which you can simulate very efficiently using a pre-allocated vector.